# Optimize sql query - select in select

Tags: mysql

Which is the best method for optimizing the select in select mysql query ?

This is my example:

```
SELECT count(distinct email) 
FROM emails_stats 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2012-12-12' 
 and email in (SELECT email 
               FROM `reminder` 
               WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2012-12-12')
```

My database has over 500k entries.

Comment: If you are only counting the email field, why do you need the emails_stats table at all? Can't you just do: SELECT count(distinct email) from `reminder` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2012-12-12') ?

Comment: @sn00k4h: no.. i can't do only select from reminder because i count emails which has been opened after i send a reminder. you understand me ?

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case something like mamdouh suggested seems to be the way to go, except that I think the 'time' field in the 2 tables are different times, so the other WHERE clause can't really be removed. I'll add a new answer with another minor modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT count(distinct emails_stats.email) 
FROM emails_stats 
JOIN reminder ON emails_stats.email= reminder.email
WHERE 
    emails_stats.time >= CAST('2012-12-12 00:00:00' AS datetime) AND
    (reminder.time BETWEEN CAST('2012-12-12 00:00:00' AS datetime) AND CAST('2012-12-12 23:59:59' AS datetime));
```

If you use date_format() with the table fields, mysql will need to go through each row in the table, because it needs to get the result of that date_format() function to be able to compare the value with your given string. To make it faster, create an index for the 'time' fields and use this query instead. That way mysql can determine which rows it needs just by looking up the index.

Answer (score -1):

Use an exists clause instead:

```
SELECT count(distinct email) 
FROM emails_stats 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2012-12-12' 
and exists (SELECT 1
                   FROM `reminder` 
                   WHERE emails_stats.email = `reminder`.email 
                   and DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2012-12-12')
```

Answer (score -1):

the best method is to use join here like

```
SELECT count(distinct emails_stats.email) 
FROM emails_stats 
JOIN reminder ON emails_stats.email= reminder.email
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(emails_stats.time, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2012-12-12';
```

Comment: you are missing `Date_Format` column in join condition.

Comment: @rs. in his query I don't think hi might need it. pretty much obvious that it's just a duplicate of emails_stats.Date_FORMAT

Comment: you cannot reference outside column in subquery when you use `IN`, so it is obvious time is coming from `reminder` table

Comment: @rs. - yes it is coming from reminder table, but still it is just to be used with the inner select and not to be used when using join in **his case**

Comment: there can be same email on other time which Op doesn't want and results/count will be wrong.

Comment: actually even in his where in. he shouldn't use it too. just not useful condition.

Comment: if so he wouldn't add the same date condition. :)

Comment: I'm not sure but did you send me a sqlfiddle. cuz I'm not seeing it?? @rs.

Comment: This answer is not equivalent to the OP's query. It will also give error as the `email` in `count(distinct email)` is ambiguous.

Comment: @ypercube - thank you for the notification about the ambiguous **updated**. but how come it's not relevant ?